is there any keyboard shortcut or way to see all windows insatces of an open application from task bar
Ubuntu 24.04
usually using VS code multiple workspaces but when need to switch beetween diffrent workspace from task bar icons of vs code, then always use to click on All Windows option and then it opnes list of all windows and we need to select a window. same for chrome and other applicaton also. see attached screenshot

so I was looking for any keyboard shotcut for the same, to get all open windows and choose/pick, although showing multiple dots near task bar icons means there are multiple instances of the application windows.

Very limited so. With the Ubuntu taskbar, one can switch to an application that is on the dock using the shortcut key Super+Number, where 'number' corresponds with the order of the icon on the dock. Hitting the keyboard combination while the application is active shows the window previews. So far so good for what you asked in the title of your question.
However, it stops when you now also want to switch windows using the keyboard. Once you see the windows, the keyboard is not active except for Esc to dismiss the window previews. It will require filing a feature request to have developers implement the keyboard support.
Alternatively, there are default key bindings that allow you to view and select windows.

The shortcut key to show all your windows in order to pick one is Super in the default Ubuntu desktop. Use arrow keys then Enter to switch to the selected window.
To see all windows of a single application, hit Alt+</kbd> (the key above <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Press <kbd> while holding Alt to cycle through the windows, release to switch to the selected window.


I tried super ( measn start button key ) + <number> ( from numpad on right side of keyboard) then the main open windows only move on the screen on left and right

oh its working after perssing esc but still the multple window moving caraousel is missing like you said but Thanks for the tip :)
